# How to alternate between two functions with javascript?

Tags: javascript

I'm currently working on a small game and am in the beginning stages. So far, I have two functions which do the following:

```
function playerAttack() {
  var newEnemy1HP = (EnemyOneStats.currentHitPoints -= PlayerStats.strength);
  EnemyOneStats.currentHitPoints = newEnemy1HP;
}

function enemyAttack() {
  var newPlayer1HP = (PlayerStats.currentHitPoints -= EnemyOneStats.strength);
  PlayerStats.currentHitPoints = newPlayer1HP;
}
```

And then utilized these functions to run them:

```
function playerAttackSim() {
  console.log("Player attacks!");
  playerAttack();
  console.log("Enemys HP:  " + EnemyOneStats.currentHitPoints);
}

function enemyAttackSim() {
  console.log("Enemy attacks!");
  enemyAttack();
  console.log("Players HP:  " + PlayerStats.currentHitPoints);
}
```

I'd like to alternate between the two until one player "dies", but can't seem to find a way to do this. I'm trying to keep the logic pretty simple here.

```
function fightTest() {
  playerAttackSim();
  if (EnemyOneStats.currentHitPoints > 0) {
    enemyAttackSim();
  } else if ((EnemyOneStats.currentHitPoints = 0)) {
    console.log("Enemy fainted. Player Wins!");
  } else if (EnemyOneStats.currentHitPoints < 0) {
    console.log("Enemy fainted. Player Wins!");
  }
  enemyAttackSim();
  if (PlayerStats.currentHitPoints > 0) {
    playerAttackSim();
  } else if ((PlayerStats.currentHitPoints = 0)) {
    console.log("Player fained. Enemy wins.");
  } else if (PlayerStats.currentHitPoints < 0) {
    console.log("Player fained. Enemy wins.");
  }
}
```

I tried this as I was pseudocoding, but that didn't alternate correctly. Instead, I wound up with player, enemy, enemy, player, and then it stopped without logging the results. Any tips? Thanks!

Comment: `if ((PlayerStats.currentHitPoints = 0))` will *not* test whether `PlayerStats.currentHitPoints` is equal to 0. Instead, it will *set* `PlayerStats.currentHitPoints` to 0. Perhaps you mean `==` instead of `=`?

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are trying to do?

```
function fightTest() {
  while (true) {
    if (PlayerStats.currentHitPoints > 0) {
      playerAttackSim();
    } else {
      console.log("Player fained. Enemy wins.");
      break;
    }

    if (EnemyOneStats.currentHitPoints > 0) {
      enemyAttackSim();
    } else {
      console.log("Enemy fainted. Player Wins!");
      break;
    }

    console.log("----------------------");
  }
}
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-f1fdj2?file=index.js)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply put the two in a loop:

```
while (true) {
  playerAttackSim();
  console.log('Player attacked; enemy hp:', EnemyOneStats.currentHitPoints);
  
  enemyAttackSim();
  console.log('Enemy attacked; player hp:', PlayerStats.currentHitPoints);
}
```

Of course, that will get you an infinite loop. We can break the loop whenever one entity manages to kill the other:

```
while (true) {
  playerAttackSim();
  console.log('Player attacked; enemy hp:', EnemyOneStats.currentHitPoints);
  if (EnemyOneStats.currentHitPoints <= 0) break;

  enemyAttackSim();
  console.log('Enemy attacked; player hp:', PlayerStats.currentHitPoints
  if (PlayerStats.currentHitPoints <= 0) break;
}
console.log('Fight is over');
```